# Chrome extension manifest v3 and inline scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

Building a chrome extension. I need to add scripts inside pages for redeclaring predefined functions (like fetch() for example). **Scripts to be loaded are part of the extension files**. What I did before is just load scripts over  tag included to page. Now when I try I have this:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following 
Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". 
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') 
is required to enable inline execution.
```

Tried to add this to the manifest

```
"content_security_policy": {
  "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-...",
  "sandbox": "none"
}
```

and got error:

```
Insecure CSP value "'sha256-...'" in directive 'script-src'.
```

and same with "nonce-" or "unsafe-inline", they all are named as insecure, and I can't load manifest with such policy.
So what should I do now with manifest v3?

Comment: Don't use inline scripts. You can do exactly the same in a separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm. And why did not I get myself? Yes, I can just add those scripts as files, not their inline content. Thanks for help wOxxOm

Comment: I'm new to Chrome extensions and am having the exact same issue - I had a v2 extension that redaclared fetch, and I want to port it to v3. How do you add these scripts as files? Thanks

Also, what if I need to inject dynamic code?

Answer (score 1):

content_security_policy's "sha-.." "nonce-.." and "unsafe-inline" workarounds are no longer valid in manifest 3